# Urlopen in urlib.request strange behaviour python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I am trying to find url's that I can't reach from a list of urls. The code is below:

```
def sanity(url,errors):
    global count
    count+=1
    if count%1000==0:
       print(count)
    try:
       if 'media' in url[:10]:
           url = "http://edoola.s3.amazonaws.com" + url
       headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36",
    }
       req=urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
       ret = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
       return 1
    except:
       print(e, url)
       errors.append(url)
       return 0

limit=1000
count=0
errors = []
with open('file.csv','r',encoding="utf-8") as file:
      text = file.read()
      text = str(text)
      urls = re.findall(r'<img.*?src=""(.*?)""[\s>]', text, flags=re.DOTALL)

arr = list(range(0,len(urls)+1,limit))
start=0
for i in arr:
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=sanity, args=(url, errors,)) for url in urls[start:i]]
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]
    if i==0:
       start=0
    else:
       start=i+1

print(errors)
with open('errors_urls.txt','w') as file:
     file.write('\n'.join(errors))
```

The code runs for 1000 properly but in the next thousand prints url's that are reachable from my chrome browser. I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984579/5658251), and [others](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html). I have tried these approaches in ipython terminal choosing a particular url and it worked fine. But when I put the same approach on the above code. I get reachable url's.  How do I solve this?

The number of urls is 15000 approx. So, in the code above I'm running in chunks of 1000, accordingly spawning 1000 threads.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the obvious indentation errors.

Comment: Are you being rate limited?

Comment: @tripleee I have fixed the indentation errors.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did not understand rate limited!! I am basically processing the urls in chunks of 1000(limit).

Comment: Rate limiting means your server, or one you are connecting to frequently, thinks you are using the network too much, and starts returning errors to defend against your attack.

Comment: The blanket `except` is certainly a bug.  What sort of errors is it printing out?

Comment: This seems way too complex for a Stack Overflow question; you should trim it down to a [mcve].